# Help with simplifying a trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

I'm currently in high school and in Pre-calc, and we have just started trig. We'll get into trig equations in a couple weeks, but I'm also in a programming class, and have a problem that I want to fix as soon as possible.

I want to draw a spiral. To do that, I have to increase the radius of a circle as it is being drawn, which is easy.

A point on a circle (x, y) is determined using $$x = X_{center} + radius \cdot cos(angle)$$ and $$y = Y_{center} + radius \cdot sin(angle)$$ Now all I have to do is add a timer, and increase the radius and angle by a certain amount each tick. Easy.

The spiral generates, except there is a minor problem. As the radius increases, so does the distance between each point on the spiral, and it looks cool, but it doesn't achieve the desired effect. I want it to look like a connected line, so I want the angle to increase by a value that will allow each point to be 1 pixel from the next so $$\sqrt{(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2} = 1$$. We can get rid of the $\sqrt{}$, so $$(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2- Y_1)^2 = 1$$ Now, the next part is going to look cluttered, so I'll write each part on a separate line.

$X_1 = X_c + r \cdot cos(a)$
$X_2 = X_c + r \cdot cos(a + x)$
$X_2 - X_1 = r \cdot (cos(a + x) - cos(a))$

$Y_1 = Y_c + r \cdot sin(a)$
$Y_2 = Y_c + r \cdot sin(a + x)$
$Y_2 - Y_1 = r \cdot (sin(a + x) - sin(a))$

$(X_2 - X_1)^2 = r^2 \cdot (cos(a + x) - cos(a))^2$
$(X_2 - Y_1)^2 = r^2 \cdot (sin(a + x) - sin(a))^2$
$(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2 = r^2 \cdot ((cos(a + x) - cos(a))^2 + (sin(a + x) - sin(a))^2)$
$(X_2 - X_1)^2 + (Y_2 - Y_1)^2 = 1$
$r^2 \cdot ((cos(a + x) - cos(a))^2 + (sin(a + x) - sin(a))^2) = 1$
$$$$
$$(cos(a + x) - cos(a))^2 + (sin(a + x) - sin(a))^2 = \frac1{r^2}$$
$$$$
The purpose of this is to express x, the change in angle, in terms of r, the radius, and a, the angle, so that with each tick, the angle is changed by a different amount, instead of a constant. What steps do I need to take next to arrive at a result? I tried several things, but I think I made a mistake somewhere with some signs or expansion, because I took up 2 pages of calculations. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on a right way.
Hint: Expand the binomials in the last line of your calculus and the relation $sin^2(x)+cos^2(x) = 1$. Moreover you must use the identity $cos(x-y)=cos(x)cos(y)+sin(x)sin(y)$. Finally you can use the function $arccos(x)$; the inverse function of the cosine.

Comment: Thanks. The cos(a + x)^2 and sin(a + x)^2 got to 1, and the same with cos(a)^2 and sin(a)^2, and the rest simplified to -2cos(x). I got that x = arccos(1 - (1 / 2r^2))

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
$$\sqrt{(x_2 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - y_1)^2} = {1}$$
which is distance of the two points, but it does not mean it is 1 pixel on screen since the pixel is for either $x=1$ or $y=1$. Plus, what is $1$ in math is not the $1$ in display. There is a scale factor in between.

Good try though.